# Retornar os números pulando de linhas

Tags: python

O código inverte a ordem dos número mas queria que também viesse pulando as linhas, por exemplo
ao invés de 321, viesse

```
3
2
1
```

segue o que foi feito:

```
  numero = 
    int(input("Entre com um número \n"))
    
    
    numero = str(numero)

print(numero[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Podemos usar o asterisco para dividir a string por caratéres e depois fazer join com o caratér de nova linha.

```
print("\n".join([*numero[::-1]]))
```